# Formatting query result

Tags: oracle

Let's say I have one query that returns column1, column2. I'd like to be able to format the result to a desirable output in Oracle.

I want to mess up with strings that's why I'm asking that question ~~.

```
create table taTest(
column1 varchar(50),
column2 varchar(50)
)
```

this is the basic query that I want to format the result from :

```
select distinct(column1),column2 from taTest;
```

```
desired output(for each query result) : column1value(column2value)
```

I've tried something like this :

```
select wm_concat(distinct(column1)||'('||column2||')') as result  from taTest;
```

But it seems like I'm not using wm_concat the right way.

Thanks for any input you might provide.

Answer (score 1):

This `distinct(column1), column2` is one of the biggest fallacies that I've seen. Because this is same as

```
select distinct column1, column2. . .
```

Hence, all you need is this

```
select
    column1 || '('|| column2 || ')' as result
from
    taTest
group by
    column1, column2;
```

In this case `group by` and `distinct` perform same function

Going back to `distinct(column1)` - this is false function. The rule of SQL parsing is that anything within `( )` considered a single word\group. Hence `(column1)` is separated from `distinct` using `()` vs empty space  -same thing. You can do

```
select distinct (column1), (column2) . . -- same thing
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I did not thing it was working this way !

Comment: @MotoIsMyMoto Well, if this is the answer you were looking for, please accept it as well